# What does "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'" mean?

Tags: php

Why am I getting the following error in PHP?

```
<?php

    require_once('validation_functions.php');
    $errors = array();

    //$username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $username = trim("");

    if(!has_presence($username))
    {
        $errors['username'] = "Username can't be left blank";
    }
?>

<?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
```

This is the following problem:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\wamp\www\sandbox\validation_functions.php on line 20

This is the file validation_functions.php detailed above

```
 <?php

function has_presence($value)
{
    //IF $value is SET AND value is NOT EXACTLY EQUAL TO "" RETURN TRUE 
    return (isset($value) && $value !== ""); //RETURNS BOOLEAN
}

function has_max_length($value, $max)
{
    //IF $value is LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO $max Return TRUE
    return (strlen($value) <= $max)); //RETURNS BOOLEAN 
}

function has_inclusion_in($value, $set)
{
    //IF $value is INCLUDED in $set RETURN TRUE 
    return in_array($value, $set); //RETURNS BOOLEAN
}

function form_errors($errors = array())
{
    $output = "";

    if(!empty($errors))
    {
        $output = "<div class= \"error\">";
        $output .= "Please Fix The Following Errors:";
        $output .= "<ul>";

        foreach($errors as $key => $error)
        {
            $output .= "<li> {$error} </li>";
        }

        $output .= "</ul>";
        $output .= "</div>";
    }

    return $output;
  }

 ?>
```

This is included in the code referenced above. It's a simple error but I can't seem to understand what's causing it.

Comment: You should post validation_functions.php, the error you are posting is in line 20, but you have only posted  18(+/-) lines

Comment: The error is at line 20 from `validation_functions.php`. You need to paste that

Comment: this error clearly tell there is some extra ")" at line 20 on validation_functions.php, please check it

Comment: PHP error reports you clearly that the file and the line number, `C:\wamp\www\sandbox\validation_functions.php`

Comment: I'm unaware of any extra ")" at line 20 after having checked sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra bracket in the marked line

```
function has_max_length($value, $max)
{
    //IF $value is LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO $max Return TRUE
 >>>>>>>>>   return (strlen($value) <= $max)); //<<<< here is a extra bracket, remove the last one!
```

Should be like this:

```
return (strlen($value) <= $max)
```

Answer (score 0):

> correct way: **return (strlen($value) <= $max);**

```
function has_max_length($value, $max)
{
//IF $value is LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO $max Return TRUE
return (strlen($value) <= $max); //RETURNS BOOLEAN 

}
```